# how can i make a field value in an array the same as the array index

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array that obviously have indexes.. i want want to take each array index an assign as a value in my array.. this is how my array looks like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 20
        [CLASS] => 1234
        [REGISTER] => 13
     )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [CLASS] => SEC
        [REGISTER] => 3
   )
)
```

want i want is to use the indexes and put them in the REGISTER field like this

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 20
        [CLASS] => 1234
        [REGISTER] => 0
     )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [CLASS] => SEC
        [REGISTER] => 1
   )
)
```

Comment: i think array_combine function will help you.check about this function or array_flip check both of this it may helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over this array like this:

```
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    $a[$k]['REGISTER'] = $k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to assign your key index to your selected value.

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value):
    $arr[$key]['REGISTER'] = $key;
endforeach;
print_r($arr);
```